# Android SIP : Ending a call before receiver picks up

Tags: android, sip

I am working on a SIP client application for Android. I am facing a problem when ending a SIP call that hasn't been answered by the receiver. I start a call using

```
call = mSipManager.makeAudioCall(mSipProfile.getUriString(), outUri, listener, 30);
```

and if I try to cancel it before it is answer i.e like giving a miss call I get an exception with following message:

> Call/Transaction Does Not Exist (481)

I use the same code to cancel a call in all cases i.e

```
call.endCall()
```

I dont see any other function in the call object that can be used instead.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, with a nexus 5 lollipop. More surprising, this behaviour is also reproductible with the native sip functionnality of the phone. It seems like a bug. Also, I saw people trying to solve the problem on Asterisk side by adding the instruction `pedantic=no` in their sip.conf. But for me, it didn't solve the problem... [This instruction](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+SIP+pedantic) tells asterisk to be less regarding when analysing paquets transaction origin